# How to use LD_PRELOAD with Android's mediaserver?

Tags: android, linker, ld-preload

I can use LD_PRELOAD with normal native apps like e.g. ls:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/library.so ls
```

After some searching I was also able to use it with java apps by setting such property:

```
adb shell setprop wrap.com.some.app LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/library.so
```

However I'm interested in using LD_PRELOAD with **mediaserver** process. This is tricky because it constantly works in the background. If you kill it, it will be started again automatically. I can start "second instance" with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/library.so /system/bin/mediaserver
```

and it will load my library although "second instance" won't be used in any playback. Always original mediaserver will handle media operations.
So is there any way to use LD_PRELOAD with mediaserver **without modifying** init.rc files on device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there is a way to do that.
I had to do following things:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb pull /system/bin/mediaserver
echo "LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/library.so /system/bin/mediaserver_orig" > mediaserver
adb shell mv /system/bin/mediaserver /system/bin/mediaserver_orig
adb push mediaserver /system/bin/mediaserver
```

Then I have killed mediaserver, which (surprisingly) wasn't started automatically, so I also had to start it by hand:

```
adb shell
/system/bin/mediaserver &
```

Anyway it is possible to do that, so I will accept my answer if nobody has anything better.

Just one **warning** - when I have returned to previous state with:

```
adb shell mv /system/bin/mediaserver_orig /system/bin/mediaserver
```

and rebooted device, mediaserver was still not started automatically! So this is not something you would like to do on device you care about because in such state if you don't start mediaserver by hand boot will not be completed by device. Although this phenomenon could have happen because I was playing with chown, so may be not related to described procedure, anyway you have been warned.